# trying to read data from textfile - It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data

Tags: java, jdbc

```
public class Txt {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
         Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:txt");
         Statement st=con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select eno,ename from emp");
         System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"   "+rs.getString(2));
     }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Don't just paste a block of code and say "help." -1

Answer (score 1):

You should **close the connection** on end of your code;

```
con.close();
```

Use this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try {
       Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
       Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:txt");
       Statement st=con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select eno,ename from emp");
       System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"   "+rs.getString(2));
      }
  catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
  catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
      }
  finally {
       // Close the connection
       con.close();
      } 
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: `con` should be declared outside `try{}` so that it is reachable in `finally{}`

Comment: Yes, It can but you should use finally. Finally runs on everycase.If you can not close connection due to an other exception, finally block runs and you can close connection safety in there.

Comment: I closed the conenction at the end. It is not working in case of reading the data from text file but it is working in case of inserting the data into text file. I am using type1 jdbc driver